# how to create multiple animations inside of a single blend file

Tags: animation

So i am creating a glass sliding door, and i have to create 2 animations,
the animation for opening,and for closing, But i do not know how.
I have tried going to dope sheet, then action editor, and created a new action but to no avail:
[PRESS ME FOR GIF LINK](https://giphy.com/gifs/3oKIP7ZzJhWxqCrDR6/fullscreen)

So if you could please help me, i would really appricate it.

Comment: When you create a new action it duplicates the current action. You can change the animation in the new action without altering the old one. Where do you want to use the different actions? In the NLA you can play the the same action backwards. For a longer animation you can have it go backwards at a different time while still in the same action. Also note that you need to click the F button to prevent losing the other action when saving and re-opening the file.

Comment: Thank you, but as a side note, is it possible to use 1 action for multiple objects?

Comment: You can use the same action on more than one object, but they will all use the same animation data, that is if the action contains rotation on the x-axis then they will all rotate the same on the x-axis. You can use the NLA editor to give each object different timing with the same action.